# William K. Bertram's sharpe formula checking

Tags: statistics, mean-reversion, stopping-time

I have some issues to verify by simulation the formulas in the paper of William K. Bertram "*[Analytic solutions for optimal statistical arbitrage trading](http://www.stagirit.org/sites/default/files/articles/a_0340_ssrn-id1505073.pdf)*".
first, the reversion parameter alpha=180 in the paper seems too high as i guess the OU will diverge after a few steps.
I am simulating X as:

```
def simulate_OU(alpha,nu,x0,T):

    X=np.zeros(T)
    X[0]=x0

    N=np.random.normal(0,1,size=T)

    delta=1

    for i in range(1,T):
        X[i]=X[i-1]-alpha*X[i-1]*delta+nu*np.sqrt(delta)*N[i]

    return X
```

if i take x0=0, alpha=180, nu=0.1538 and T=100 The process diverges. Alpha should normally be <1 Could someone show me what i am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: My *guess* (although I did not find this in the paper) is that things are being done in units of *years*, and therefore if you want to simulate daily you need $delta=\frac{1}{365}$. Then alpha*delta will be less than half.